# QTabWidget insert a QSplitter can't switch when the splitter disabled

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtabwidget, qsplitter

I insert a QFrame and QTabWidget in the QSplitter. And I wanna forbidden to adjust the size of elements in QSplitter. So I call method of 'setDisabled' in QSplitter. It's useful for disabling resizing the elements. But I also can't switch tab of QTabWidget. Who can give me some suggestions? Thanks very much......

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QSplitter, QHBoxLayout, QFrame, QTabWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
class Example1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 600, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle("Demo")
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()

        top_frame = QFrame()
        top_frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)

        bottom_frame = QTabWidget(self)
        tab1 = QWidget()
        tab2 = QWidget()
        bottom_frame.setTabText(0, "Generic")
        bottom_frame.setTabText(1, "Other")
        bottom_frame.addTab(tab1, "Tab 1")
        bottom_frame.addTab(tab2, "Tab 2")

        splitter = QSplitter()
        splitter.setOrientation(Qt.Vertical)
        splitter.addWidget(top_frame)
        splitter.addWidget(bottom_frame)
        splitter.setSizes([300, 300])
        **splitter.setDisabled(True)**

        self.layout.addWidget(splitter)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example1()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

the running result of the program

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you disable a widget you also disable its children, so disabling the QSplitter also disables the QTabWidget.

A possible solution is enable or disable the handles:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QFrame,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QSplitter,
    QSplitterHandle,
    QTabWidget,
    QWidget,
)


class CustomSplitter(QSplitter):
    @property
    def enabled(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "_enabled"):
            self._enabled = True
        return self._enabled

    @enabled.setter
    def enabled(self, d):
        self._enabled = d
        for i in range(self.count()):
            self.handle(i).setEnabled(self.enabled)

    def createHandle(self):
        handle = super().createHandle()
        handle.setEnabled(self.enabled)
        return handle


class Example1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 600, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle("Demo")
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()

        top_frame = QFrame()
        top_frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)

        bottom_frame = QTabWidget(self)
        tab1 = QWidget()
        tab2 = QWidget()
        bottom_frame.setTabText(0, "Generic")
        bottom_frame.setTabText(1, "Other")
        bottom_frame.addTab(tab1, "Tab 1")
        bottom_frame.addTab(tab2, "Tab 2")

        splitter = CustomSplitter()
        splitter.setOrientation(Qt.Vertical)
        splitter.addWidget(top_frame)
        splitter.addWidget(bottom_frame)
        splitter.setSizes([300, 300])

        splitter.enabled = False

        self.layout.addWidget(splitter)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example1()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your method has successfully solved my confusion.

Comment: @LA.Steve  If answer helped you then do not forget to mark as correct, 
if you do not know how to do it then check the https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used a QSplitter before but are the `.setFixedHeight(300)` `.setFixedWidth(300)`, or `.setFixedSize(300, 300)` methods not applicable here?

Comment: Thank you sincerely.It's working for disabling resizing the elements after i do this.Also i would like to  know what caused the conflict as stated in my question.

Comment: @LA.Steve Disabling widgets is a recursive operation in Qt, so all children get disabled as well.

Answer (score 0):

QSplitter lets you get hold of its handles, which are the GUI element visible to the user. If you have two widgets in a splitter, you have a single visible handle; the handle at index 0 is always invisible.

You can manipulate that widget explicitely, e.g. disable it. Try:

```
splitter.handle(1).enabled = False
```

This disables only said GUI element, while the rest of the splitter (your two content widgets) will stay enabled.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get it. But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Interesting. It is basically the same as what @eyllanesc is doing. Anyways, glad you found a solution to your problem!